# Running java through PHP from source file and save output

Tags: java, php, exec

I am developing an online coding competition application. In this I want the code submitted to be compiled and executed. If the submitted code is in Java I am able to compile it using `exec` (javac filename).

But how should I run that code such so it will take input from a file and redirect the output to another file? Any other way to check that code for various test cases will also be useful.

```
exec('java ./$path > ./$dest')
```

This is what I am using to execute but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed with the string interpolation, so you should use:

```
$path = "path/to/java/file.java";
$dest = "path/to/output.o";
exec("java ./{$path} > ./{$dest}")
```

**But it lacks some basic security considerations.**

Unless you want a smart-enough user to execute whatever code he likes on your machine, remember:

### Running user-submitted java code definitely requires some sandboxing.

And exec is dangerous. Consider a system call in that java file executing `rm -rf ~`. I bet there's some java or php alternative for [stuff like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandbox), that would execute it in a more or less safe environment.

Also, if I pass `$dest = '../../some/evil/path/file.o'`, then  the file would be in the directory you don't expect it to (but I guess it's not so critical since you set those paths).